# eclipse mercurial plugin display arrow instead of changeset

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

How can set eclipse to display an arrow with a number of commits till last pull instead of a changset near a project name?

[image: Project explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a recent version of MercurialEclipse, by default, you should not see the revision number nor hash. Instead you will see current tag (if any) and the number of "unpublished" changesets with arrow. This usually corresponds to the number of "outgoing" changesets.

Here is the project home: https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/wiki/Home, and here is the stable update site:    http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable

Comment: I am sorry I coldn't reply earlier. I the previous version I was seeing number of outgoing changesets by default. Now, in 2.3.2 its the revision number. The solution you provided in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905782/mercurialeclipse-how-to-set-label-decorations/23252955?iemail=1&noredirect=1#23252955 does not work.

Comment: The latest development version is 2.1.1. Where did you get 2.3.2 from?

Comment: From here: http://javaforge.com/project/HGE I checked the version thru Eclipse -> show installed software, which says 2.3.2. A friend of mine uses different version and he has an addiional checkbox in the preferences: "show number of heads and unpublished changesets" which does the trick.

Comment: The update site on javaforge.com/project/HGE hasn't been updated for a few years as far as I know. Use the bitbucket home page (update site hosted on google code for now).

Comment: I've uninstalled previous version and installed a new one from the update site you proposed. Everything works as previous. Thanks! Voted.