# mercurialeclipse - how to set label decorations?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

How can I set label decorations for Mercurial managed projects? It's somehow set to changeset@project name. Previous version of the plugin used to show arrows and a number of changeset in local repository, which I liked a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your other question here: [eclipse mercurial plugin display arrow instead of changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837049/eclipse-mercurial-plugin-display-arrow-instead-of-changeset)

There is 1 configuration options under: Window->Preferences->Team->Mercurial->Performance. The 3rd checkbox